# Calculate and record recurring dates

Tags: date, record, recurring

I need to find out which dates will apear until 2016-12-31, for the following situation:
I have a initial and a final date;
I have a specific frequency for each record;

Eg:

```
motor -        $date_ini = 2016-01-01 - $freq = 30 (days)

reductor -     $date_ini = 2016-01-01 - $freq = 10 (days)

hidraulic -    $date_ini = 2016-01-01 - $freq = 20 (days)

pump-          $date_ini = 2016-01-01 - $freq = 10 (days)

I need to record the result in a table for a later consulting:

id01 - motor -  2016-02-01

id02 - motor -  2016-03-01

id03 - motor -  2016-04-01

...

id.. - motor -  2016-12-01

...

id.. - reductor -  2016-01-10

id.. - reductor -  2016-01-20

id.. - reductor -  2016-01-30

...
```

and so on...

I have tried this way, but it didnt work, gave me an eternal loop.

```
$endDate = "2016-12-31";

$myDates = array();

$finished = false;

while(!$finished){

$quebrarDatasd = explode("-", $result['date_ini']); list($anop, $mesp, $diap) = 

$quebrarDatasd;

$lastDate = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0, $mesp, $diap + $result['freq'], $anop));

if(strtotime($lastDate) > strtotime($endDate)){ $finished = true; break; }

$myDates[] = $lastDate; }
```

How may I proceed?